# Transfer Items between Views in same Part with Drag-and-Drop in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop

How can I switch the views during DnD?
Both views must be in the same part and I would like to activate/switch the view with dragging onto the view title.

Comment: Are asking about coding this in a plugin? Is the Eclipse 3.x compatability mode or e4? By 'same part' I take it you mean the same part stack.

Comment: Yes, it is in a plugin are better the views are own plugins each. 
It must be 3.x compatibility mode but if it is only possible in e4 it's good to know for the switch decision. 
'Same part" means the title tabs are in the same row so yes I think its the same part stack. But should working between parts stacks too.